# Ansible: Conditional Tasks Pattern & Site Layout

Tags: ansible

I've been playing around with ansible (I'm very new to configuration management in general, it's not what I do for my
dayjob), and I'm trying to figure out the best way to pattern my conditional tasks.

I've structured my setup (git repository with the following layout:

```
├── dotfiles (...)
├── bin (...)
└── playbooks
    ├── bootstrap.yml
    ├── firewall.yml
    ├── ids.yml
    ├── logserver.yml
    ├── pvr.yml
    ├── site.yml
    ├── log
    └── roles
        └── bootstrap
        |  ├── defaults
        |  │   └── main.yml
        |  └── tasks
        |      ├── apt-update.yml
        |      ├── apt-upgrade.yml
        |      ├── homebrew-user.yml
        |      ├── homebrew-install.yml
        |      ├── homebrew-update.yml
        |      ├── homebrew-upgrade.yml
        |      ├── main.yml
        |      ├── tmux-install.yml
        |      └── vim-install.yml
        ├── elk     (...)
        ├── snort   (...)
        ├── tor     (...)
        └── zentyal (...)
```

For most scenarios, I've got a playbook for each system that I'm using to buildout my roles. I run the playbook locally
on each host (on my firewall system, i log in, update the git repository, and run `ansible-playbook bootstrap.yml` and
`ansible-playbook firewall.yml`. My intent is to setup a real inventory in the future so that I can run specific roles
against specific hosts, but for now while I'm learning, this works well.

Most of the roles are platform specific and require sudo, and that's fine and works well.

However my `bootstrap.yml` playbook needs to run in *variable* environments:

- sometimes install homebrew on an osx system using sudo (multi-user environment)
- sometimes install homebrew on an osx system without sudo (single-user environment)
- sometimes install additional homebrew applications in a specific location (single-user desktop system)
- sometimes install additional homebrew applications in a specific location (multiuser desktop system)
- sometimes install specific applications system-wide using package control on Ubuntu/BSD systems
- sometimes install specific applications using local build scripts on Ubuntu/BSD systems in $HOME

Depending on the environment, there's up to 100 applications or so that I'd like to bootstrap - all the various
utilities that I use for daily things - copying over my dotfiles, installing/updating bash/zsh, git,
git-flow, hub, vim, tmux, mosh, weechat, base16, source-highlight, netcat, nmap, setting up pip, virtualenv,
virtualenvwrapper, and about 100 other things.

As a single example, a task for installing tmux in multiple environments (in *python-like* psuedocode):

```
if ansible_distribution=='MacOSX':
    if sudo_user is not None:
        homebrew: name=tmux state=present sudo_user='homebrew'
    else:
        homebrew: name=tmux state=present
elif os=='Ubuntu':
    if sudo_user is not None:
        apt_repository: name='ppa:pi-rho' state: present)
        apt: name=tmux state=present sudo_user='root')
    else:
        shell: tmux-ubuntu-build-local.sh
elif os=='BSD':
        shell: tmux-bsd-build-local.sh
```

But ansible doesn't seem to have basic if/else constructs available - just the `when` construct. So , I started using
`when` to write conditional tasks (included by `./playbooks/roles/bootstrap/main.yml`):

```
---
# ./playbooks/roles/bootstrap/tmux.yml

# this always installs without sudo, which works on my laptop
# but fails on shared systems that use a 'homebrew' user
- name: install
  when: ansible_distribution == 'MacOSX'
  sudo: no
  homebrew: name=tmux

# i only want to run this when I *want* to install tmux globally
# on some systems I just want to run a build script
# if i don't have root and visudo isn't properly configured, this fails
- name: add pi-rho/dev ppa
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
  sudo: yes
  apt_repository: 
    repo: 'ppa:pi-rho/dev'
    state: present

# again, i don't always want to do this
- name: update cache
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
  sudo: yes
  apt: update_cache=yes

# this always attempts to install using sudo, which I don't want.
# on some systems I want to run a build script that installs tmux
# to the user's home directory instead
- name: install
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
  sudo: yes
  apt: name=tmux

# this installs a set of tmux plugins without sudo to my $HOME
# directory, i do always want this
- name: install plugins
  sudo: no
  git:
    repo: '{{ item.repo }}'
    dest: '{{ tmux_plugins_path }}/plugins/{{ item.name }}'
  with_items: tmux_plugins
```

This approach works on a couple of my systems, but fails (as the comments note) in all but the most basic cases. It also
scales *very* poorly - as I don't see a way to "reuse" any of the tasks or to use multiple/chained `when` expressions
with a single task.

I've started playing with several other solutions I've read about:

1. Pass in a flag using -e, for example: use_sudo, but again, without *"task reuse"* I'm going to have to write
   individual tasks for each application/library to account for the flag. And if I also did this with the operating
   system (`-e os=macosx`), this scales even worse.
2. Tag all my tasks at the role level - this required me to split out tasks into separate roles by OS rather than
   *"topic"*, which was counter-interuitive, and difficult to work with.
3. Tag all my tasks at the task level - again, without task reuse, this seems to scale very badly.
4. I've considered looking plugins/modules to see if I can write something up in Python to make enable if/else constructs
   in a single task or "nested" tasks, and if I can't figure something more simple out, that's probably what I'll look into
   next.

So, am I *doing it wrong*? Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see you doing anything specifically _wrong_. But this is very much _personal opinion/preference/linking_ approach. There's no right or wrong way to approach this. Perhaps a better place for this would be Ansible's forum, since you'll unlikely get a canonical answer for this on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Conditional Imports
or Applying ‘when’ to roles and includes described in
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_conditionals.html